# How to change Position of Imageview with button in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

So Im supernew to Kotlin so im trying to create a simple game where if I press a button an Imageview will shift left or right. Below I tried using ObjectAnimator and it works. When I press the button it shifts to the right but it only does that only once on runtime. As it stands now I have one button programmed but I hope to have 4 directional buttons where I can move an Imageview around the screen. So How can I keep changing the position of an imageview when the app is running ?

Thank You!

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    //val picture = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.SpongeBob)
    val position_button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.position_button)


    position_button.setOnClickListener()
    {
        ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(SpongeBob, "TranslationX", 100f).apply {
            duration = 200
            start()

        }

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `picture.animate().setDuration(200).translationXBy(100f)`, be sure to type `translationXBy` and not `translationX`! You can also use `"translationXBy"` in your `ObjectAnimator` or use a variable instead of `100f`.

What you are doing right now is moving the picture to `x: 100` all the time, but what you really want is to move it **by** 100.

I made a small demo for you [here](https://github.com/rtsketo/ImageGame/blob/master/app/src/main/java/eu/rtsketo/imagegame/MainActivity.kt).

[image]

Comment: you sir just made my day ! Thank you so much for your help I got it to work :)

Comment: And thanks for making the demo, it will be helpful for future use